# Use values from XML to create XML with XSL

Tags: xml, xslt

I have a XML from a MySQL Query output which looks as following:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<resultset statement="SELECT product_id, product_price FROM products WHERE 1" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"></resultset>
<row>
  <field name="product_id"123456</field>
  <field name="product_price"12.55</field>
</row>
<row>
  <field name="product_id"9999</field>
  <field name="product_price"4.95</field>
</row>
</resultset>
```

I am using the following xsl script:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<xsl:output indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="resultset">
    <products>
        <vendor>vendor_123</vendor>
        <timestamp></timestamp>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </products>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="row">
    <product>
    <product_code custid="{field[@name='product_id']}"> </product_code>
    <price> <xsl select="{field[@name='product_price']}"/> </price>
    </product>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The xml I get is:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<products>
 <vendor>vendor_123</vendor>
 <timestamp/>
 <product>
  <product_code custid="123456"/>
  <price> <xsl select="12.55"/> </price>
 </product>
 <product>
  <product_code custid="9999"/>
  <price> <xsl select="4.95"/> </price>
 </product>
</products>
```

The XML I would like to get is:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<products>
 <vendor>vendor_123</vendor>
 <timestamp/>
 <product>
  <product_code>123456<product_code>
  <price>12.55</price>
 </product>
 <product>
  <product_code>9999</product_code>
  <price>4.95</price>
 </product>
</products>
```

For the price I tried
<xsl:value-of select="{field[@name='product_price']}"/>

but unfortunately it throws me the error:

XPath error: Invalid expression
{field[@name='product_price']}

compilation error: file script.xslt line 19 element value-of
xsl:value-of : could not compile select expression '{field[@name='product_price']}'

What is the right expression to use the values as a result in the xml element.
Thank you

Comment: The input you show is not a well-formed XML, which makes it time-consuming to reproduce your problem. Please be more careful next time.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of:

```
<xsl select="{field[@name='product_price']}"/>
```

use:

```
<xsl:value-of select="field[@name='product_price']"/>
```